# Yii2 isnewrecord generates exception

Tags: yii2

In yii2 set-up I have multiple models - one being one to many with repeat fields in form where I can edit fieldset or add new records.

but I am facing issue of duplicate key error.

To overcome the same I am trying this code:

```
try{
     $userchild->save();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
    $userchild->isNewRecord = false;
    $usrchild->save();
}
```

but I am getting the exception:

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: app\controllers\UserController::setIsNewRecord()
```

What I am missing here?

update with more code:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

    $model->username = $model->email;
    $model->save();
    $profile->save();
    $billinginfo->save();
    if (!empty($_POST['UserChildren']) && !is_null($_POST['UserChildren'])) {
     foreach($_POST['UserChildren'] as $rows){

           $userchild = New UserChildren;                            
           $userchild->user_id = $model->id; 
           $userchild->id =$rows['id'];
           $userchild->attributes=$rows;  
           try{
                $userchild->save();
              } catch(\Exception $e){                            
                $userchild->setIsNewRecord(false);
           $usrchild->save();
            }
       }

  }
```

Now I am getting the error:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\UserChildren::_attributes
```

Comment: This works for you?  $userchild->setIsNewRecord(false);?

Comment: The problem is most likely because there is no method called `setIsNewRecord`. And the part of code you gave is probably not enough here.

Comment: which class is for $userchild ?  . are yiu sure the extend an activeRecord ?

Comment: which is your actual real  question  .. the setIsNewRecord() or the _attributes??????

Answer (score 0):

if you want assigng  the attributes you should  use

```
 $userchild->setAttributes($rows, TRUE);
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#$attributes-detail

Comment: Actually I want to update if rows are present and add when I add a row. I have added the code you recommended before save method. I am getting this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '28' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `user_children` (`user_id`, `id`, `child_name`, `child_birth_date`, `child_gender`) VALUES (73, 28, 'Ram1', '2008-06-15', 'Male')`

Comment: this is clear ...  you are attempting to insert a rows  with a primary key value that already exist.  . .seemsthat . you create a new model  and after you assign existing value  .. could be you must eval deeper what you are trying to do.. or you should not assign al the attribute but only a part ..

Comment: so what is the best solution. I have the model UserChildren related to User. UserChildren have many records related to User. I am able to add records also add rows dynamically in the form. The data is saved correctly in the UserChildren table. when I open the form for edit it is displaying all the data in the table correctly. Now the problem starts. say if I ignore the line ` $userchild->id =$rows['id'];` then it inserts new record, if I keep it there is a duplicate key error. That is where I was looking for the solution using the function `setIsNewRecord(false)`

Comment: when you update .. you should create new models only if you really have new models .. but if (or when)  you have not new model then you should not ..use  a  created new model