# PHP ignore foreach on condition

Tags: php, yii2

I have some line of records which I want to iterate in foreach if it is not empty.

my code is like this:

```
$count =2;
if($count > 0){     
foreach($userchild as $userchild){?>
<?php } ?>

//some html fields

?php
if($count > 0){
        }
    }
```

The above code generates error when empty, but if I comment foreach lines it works.

for example:

```
$count =2
if($count > 0){     
   // foreach($userchild as $userchild){?>
    <?php } ?>

    //some html fields

    ?php
    if($count > 0){
   //         }
        }
```

What I am missing here and how I can ignore foreach if count > 0

update _form code:

```
$count =2;
if($count > 0){

foreach($userchild as $userchild){?>
<?php } ?>

    <div id="kids">
    <div class="r-group">  
    <div class="form-group form-material"> 

 <?= $form->field($userchild,  '['.$id.']'.'child_name')->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Name','class' => 'col-sm-4','data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_name]', 'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_name-++'])->label(FALSE)?>



<?= $form->field($userchild, '['.$id.']'.'child_birth_date')->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Birth Date', 'class' => 'col-sm-4','data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_birth_date]', 'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_birth_date-++'])->label(FALSE)?>

 <?= $form->field($userchild, '['.$id.']'.'child_gender')->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Gender', 'class' => 'col-sm-4','data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_gender]', 'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_gender-++'])->label(FALSE)?>
        </div>            
            </div>

<?php
if($count > 0){
}
}

 ?>
```

controller code:

```
public function actionUpdateProfile() {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model = User::find()->where(['id' => $user_id])->one();

    $UserProfile = UserProfile::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->one();
            $userbillinginfo = UserBillingInfo::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->one();
            $userchildren = UserChildren::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->all();
            //var_dump($userchildren);

        if($userchildren){
        $profile = $UserProfile;
                    $billinginfo= $userbillinginfo; 
                    $userchild = $userchildren;                      
            } 

            else {
        $profile = new UserProfile;                        
        $profile->user_id = $model->id;
                    $billinginfo = new UserBillingInfo;
                    $billinginfo->user_id = $model->id;                        
                    $userchild = New UserChildren;
                    $userchild->user_id = $model->id;

    }
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $profile->load($_POST)) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($profile);
    }

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $billinginfo->load($_POST)) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($billinginfo);
    }

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $userchild->load($_POST)) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($userchild);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        //UserChildren::deleteAll('user_id = '. $model->id);
        $model->username = $model->email;
        $model->save();
        $profile->save();
        $billinginfo->save();


if (!empty($_POST['UserChildren']) && !is_null($_POST['UserChildren'])) {
           foreach($_POST['UserChildren'] as $rows){ 
$userchild = New UserChildren;
                         Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('user_children', ['child_name' => $rows['child_name'],'child_birth_date' =>$rows['child_birth_date'],'child_gender' =>$rows['child_gender']])->execute();
            $userchild->user_id = $model->id; 
            $userchild->attributes=$rows;  
            $userchild->save();
                        }
                }             

            return $this->redirect(['view']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update-profile', [
                'model' => $model,
                'profile' => $profile,
                 'billinginfo' => $billinginfo,
                 'userchild' => $userchild,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

now I am using `$userchild as userchild` not as `array as item`
so when ignoring thee foreach default is $userchild in fieldnames which is coming from controller.

Comment: Whats the error? `?php` is a typo but shouldnt cause an error ... or looking at it more... you are trying to use the array as a string `$userchild as $userchild`.

Comment: Can you like reformat your code? also, why don't you use `foreach():` and `endforeach;`? it's more readable..

Comment: You might be getting null in $userchild value. can add check condition before foreach like count($userchild) then likewise

Comment: @Th3 - exactly the error is like - `Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null`

Comment: but > 0 is the count, where I want to ignore the code if count is 0

Comment: Can you change the variable name in foreach parameter i guess it wont be a problem but just try

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of the real code, with sample data so we can reproduce?

Comment: if condition which is checking $count is statically coded, you should be changing your code to $count = count($userchild).

Comment: iterating with same variable $userchild as $userchild, shouldn't you change it to like $array as $item or likewise. In you case both are same.

Comment: ok updating with more info.

Comment: You can't make PHP code itself conditional. What you want is `if (...) { foreach (...) { ... } }`; i.e. just put the entire `foreach (...) { ... }` block into an `if (...) { ... }` block, not the opening and closing statements separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple use a  proper echo of all the part  of code you need, avoiding mixing code, eg:

```
<?php  
    $count =2;
    if($count > 0){

      foreach($userchild as $userchild){

        echo '<div id="kids">
        <div class="r-group">  
        <div class="form-group form-material"> ';

         echo  $form->field($userchild,  '['.$id.']'.'child_name')
                 ->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Name','class' => 'col-sm-4',
                       'data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_name]',
                        'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_name-++'])->label(FALSE);

        echo  $form->field($userchild, '['.$id.']'.'child_birth_date')
                 ->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Birth Date', 'class' => 'col-sm-4',
                         'data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_birth_date]', 
                         'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_birth_date-++'])->label(FALSE);

        echo $form->field($userchild, '['.$id.']'.'child_gender')
                  ->textInput( ['placeholder' => 'Kids Gender', 'class' => 'col-sm-4',
                         'data-pattern-name' => 'UserChildren[++][child_gender]', 
                         'data-pattern-id' => 'userchildren-child_gender-++'])->label(FALSE);
         echo '</div>            
                    </div>';

      } // end foreach  
  } // end if($count > 0){
?>
```

Comment: Actually when I took the entire block in the condition it worked. Thanks for your alternate suggestion as well.

Comment: @Joshi  ..if my answer is correct  .. or lead you to the right solution  .. you should mark it as accepted .

Comment: accepted. I am having some other issues. can you take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592758/yii2-isnewrecord-generates-exception

Answer (score 1):

You can use one query:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading

```
$model = User::find()->with(['userprofile','userbillinginfo','userchildren'])->where(['id' => $user_id])->one();

if(isset($model->userchildren)) {
   foreach($model->userchildren as $child) {
       ....
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your PHP syntax is not correct.
Please have a try like this.

```
$count =2;
if($count > 0){     
foreach($userchild as $userchild){
<?php } ?>

//some html fields
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why syntax issue do you think the OP has?

Comment: if I don't put a condition on ending brace and count is 0, it will generate error for incorrect end of file.